# Java if/else, while and user input

Tags: java

```
        System.out.print("Hi " + name + ", which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens? ");

        String userChoice = null;

        while ((!userChoice.equals("O")) || (!userChoice.equals("E"))) {

            userChoice = input.nextLine();
        }

        if ( userChoice.equals("O") ) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked odds! The computer will be evens.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! The computer will be odds.");
        }
```

Cheers guys,

I am new to Java and I have no clue why this is not working. I want to ask the user for his choice until he chooses "O" or "E". Otherwise re-ask the user for his input. Therefore my idea was to check if userChoice does not equal "O" or "E" > ask again.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I get this error when running the code:

> Let´s play a game called "Odds and Evens"
> What is your name? Ron
> Hi Ron, which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens? Exception in thread "main" > java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.ronwalter.Main.main(Main.java:18)
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: because   String userChoice = null in the first time

Comment: Note that apart from the error you are currently getting your loop: `while ((!userChoice.equals("O")) || !(userChoice.equals("E")))` can only end in an infinite loop because your userChoice will always be not equal to at least one of your conditions that you linked with an or

Comment: Change String userChoise . The nullpointer ref to this as stated in the console as well. Also you have to end the loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

because `String userChoice = null`

if `String userChoice == null` the while statement is:

`while((!null.equals("O")) || (!null.equals("E")))`

this is the reason that you get `NullPointerException`

**The solution is the set userChoice to empty string:**

```
    System.out.print("Hi " + name + ", which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens? ");

    String userChoice = "";<-------must set value!!!!

    while ((!userChoice.equals("O")) || (!userChoice.equals("E"))) {

        userChoice = input.nextLine();
    }

    if ( userChoice.equals("O") ) {
        System.out.println(name + " has picked odds! The computer will be evens.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! The computer will be odds.");
    }
```